# error TS2339: Property 'DEFAULT_TTS_HOST' does not exist on type 'typeof ApiAiConstants'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am following this [tutorial](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/chatbot-in-angular-with-dialogflow-api-ai/) for making chatbot with angular. I get following error:

ERROR in node_modules/api-ai-javascript/ts/Request/TTSRequest.ts(17,31): error TS2339: Property 'DEFAULT_TTS_HOST' does not exist on type 'typeof ApiAiConstants'.

I am using Angular & Angular CLI version: 6.0.3.

```
import {ApiAiClient} from "../ApiAiClient";
import {ApiAiConstants} from "../ApiAiConstants";
import {ApiAiClientConfigurationError, ApiAiRequestError} from "../Errors";
import {IRequestOptions} from "../Interfaces";
import XhrRequest from "../XhrRequest";
import Request from "./Request";

export class TTSRequest extends Request {

  private static RESPONSE_TYPE_ARRAYBUFFER = "arraybuffer";

  private static audioContext: AudioContext;

  constructor(protected apiAiClient: ApiAiClient, options: IRequestOptions = {}) {
    super(apiAiClient, options);
    // this.requestMethod = XhrRequest.Method.GET;
    this.uri = ApiAiConstants.DEFAULT_TTS_HOST;
    const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || webkitAudioContext;

    if (!TTSRequest.audioContext) {
      TTSRequest.audioContext = new AudioContext();
    }
  }
"TTSREquest.ts" 84L, 2506C
```

Comment: Could you add the definition of ApiAiConstants?

Comment: @kristaps - Here is the repo for it, https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-javascript-client/blob/master/ts/ApiAiConstants.ts - there is no value at all for it, so it's hard to determine what value to assign this constant like the rest of the constants used this namespace (e.g. what possible URI string to use for the constant if we do overwrite the package back at src)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is correct, Typescript complains that you do not have a variable  named **`DEFAULT_TTS_HOST`** in your **`ApiAiConstants`** file.

To fix this add a variable as follows,

```
export const DEFAULT_TTS_HOST: string = "https://api.api.ai/api/tts";
```

**[`EXAMPLE PROJECT`](https://github.com/jack-le-nus/ChatBotClient/blob/bb95b931084d2f879ad594773f0db4bda68780bd/ts/ApiAiConstants.ts)**

In order to explain in detail, if you look at the original repo you posted it internally uses this [`library`](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-javascript-client)

```
import {ApiAiClient} from "api-ai-javascript";
```

if you look at the particular library it has the constant defined in the [`file`](https://github.com/Faithlife/api-ai-javascript/blob/master/src/ApiAiConstants.ts)

Comment: Where did you find this string value? Was this defined in an older repo?

Comment: Can you link the version?

Comment: what do you mean by version ?

Comment: I wanted to know if you found the string defined with this constant value from an official source of Ai API (e.g. - a previous github version of the package). The URI you provided is different from DEFAULT_BASE_URL (https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-javascript-client/blob/master/ts/ApiAiConstants.ts). I'm hoping to find confirmation on the true value of the intended URI string is meant to be to make sure if ever this constant is used, it really is pointing to the right URI.

Comment: yes if you look at your original source it imports the library "import {ApiAiClient} from "api-ai-javascript";" which intern uses this internally https://github.com/Faithlife/api-ai-javascript/blob/master/src/ApiAiConstants.ts

Answer (score 1):

I got this error fixed in my app , but took a few changes to get it to work. My first issue was "ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.". Then I tried a few suggestions, but started to see the DEFAULT_TTS_HOST error. The various suggestions only worked to solve part of the issue. This combination of changes fixed the problem and I was able to build successfully.

I'm using Angular 6.0.9, Angular Cli 6.0.8, api-ai-javascript, 2.0.0-beta.21, typescript 2.7.2 ( I was using the latest version, but its appeared to not be supported for angular cli, had to go back 2.7.2)

1. First change: 
   I did go in and fix the ApiAiConstants in the node_modules for api-ai-javascript. The differences were it had double quotes instead of single quotes around the defined values(changed to single quote), and added the DEFAULT_TTS_HOST line, so it ended up looking like this:

   ```
   export namespace ApiAiConstants {
       export enum AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES {
               EN = 'en' as any, DE = 'de' as any, ES = 'es' as any, PT_BR = 'pt-BR' as any, ZH_HK = 'zh-HK' as any,ZH_CN = 'zh-CN' as any, ZH_TW = 'zh-TW' as any, NL = 'nl' as any, FR = 'fr' as any, IT = 'it' as any, JA = 'ja' as any, KO = 'ko' as any, PT = 'pt' as any, RU = 'ru' as any, UK = 'uk' as any }

         export const VERSION = '2.0.0-beta.21';
         export const DEFAULT_BASE_URL = 'https://api.api.ai/v1/';
         export const DEFAULT_API_VERSION = '20150910';
         export const DEFAULT_CLIENT_LANG: AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES = AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES.EN;
         export const DEFAULT_TTS_HOST = 'https://api.api.ai/api/tts';
   }
   ```

   Note: I had to change the version, I had 21 installed, but it was showing 20.
2. I then ran this build command:

   ```
   ng serve --aot
   ```

   This was a suggestion that did not fix my issue, but I did get a different error message. It was complaining about my main.ts and polyfills missing from Typescript collection. For that I added both of those to the tsconfig.spec.json. Like this:

   ```
   },
     "files": [
          "test.ts",
          "polyfills.ts",
          "main.ts"
     ],
   ```

I also added this to the tsconfig.app.json, but this may not be necessary. I didn't get rid of the error, until I added the settings above to the tsconfig.spec.json:

```
"include":[
    "../node_modules/api-ai-javascript/ts/*.ts",
    "../node_modules/api-ai-javascript/**/*.ts",
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
```

Then it built successfully.

One added note, if it only works to build with ng serve --aot, add this to the tsconfig.app.json to fix that:

```
"files": [
         "../src/app/app.module.ts"
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, you should not make any changes in node_modules.
Rather than making changes in node_modules, use more specific version of **api-ai-javascript**.
Try re-installing this package with this command-

> **npm install api-ai-javascript@2.0.0-beta.16**

In this version you don't need to add DEFAULT_TTS_HOST in your node_modules.
This should solve your issue, to learn more about versions, you can visit

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/api-ai-javascript#200-beta21